# Create variable based on first observation of a group in R / Rstudio

Tags: r, data.table

i have a data.table, and trying to create a new variable based on the first observation of a group e.g. :

```
    ID, Month, Value
    A    Jan     5
    A    Feb     10
    A    Mar     7
    B    Feb     3
    B    Mar     6
```

desired output:

```
    ID, Month, Value First.Month
    A    Jan     5      Jan
    A    Feb     10     Jan
    A    Mar     7      Jan
    B    Feb     3      Feb
    B    Mar     6      Feb
```

I am working in Rstudio, any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can group by 'ID' and assign (`:=`) the first element of 'Month' i.e. 'Month[1L]' (`1L` is just a integer representation, it can be dropped to `1`) to create the 'First.Month'

```
library(data.table)
dt[, First.Month := Month[1L], by = ID]
dt
#   ID Month Value First.Month
#1:  A   Jan     5         Jan
#2:  A   Feb    10         Jan
#3:  A   Mar     7         Jan
#4:  B   Feb     3         Feb
#5:  B   Mar     6         Feb
```

Note: If it is not a `data.table`, convert to `data.table` first

```
setDT(dt)
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you for the answer and the detailed explanation